# emmeans ignoring `adjust`

Tags: r, p-value, contrasts, generalized-least-squares, lsmeans

I am running a `gls` on a repeated measures design. I am trying to check if my contrasts are being adjusted but I am failing to get any adjustment using either `emmeans` or `rstatix` packages.

#### Generate the data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
library(ggpubr)

values_treat <- function(){
  return(c(5, 1, 5) + rnorm(3))
}
values_ctrl <- function(){
  return(c(5, 5, 5) + rnorm(3))
}
values <- c(unlist(replicate(expr=values_treat(), n=10, simplify = F)),
            unlist(replicate(expr=values_ctrl(), n=10, simplify = F)))
# data
df <- tibble(
  day = factor(rep(1:3, 20)),
  id = factor(sort(rep(LETTERS[1:20], 3))),
  treat = c(rep("treat", 30), rep("ctrl", 30)),
  value = values
)
```

This is the model I'm fitting

```
m1 <- nlme::gls(data = df,
          model = value ~ treat*day, 
          correlation = nlme::corIdent(form = ~1|day))
```

There is clear interaction as you can see from the plot (see bottom) and the `anova(m1)`:

```
Denom. DF: 54 
            numDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1 1089.3321  <.0001
treat           1   22.8975  <.0001
day             2   14.2477  <.0001
treat:day       2   27.7378  <.0001
```

So I am interested in testing the difference between groups by day. To do so, I was using `pwpp` function because it gives me the pvalues associated with the `emmeans` object.

```
em_contrast <- emmeans::emmeans(object = m1, data=df,
                                specs = "treat", by = "day",
                                adjust="BH") %>% 
  emmeans::pwpp(by="day")
```

```
> em_contrast$data
day = 1:
 contrast     estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value plus  minus midpt
 ctrl - treat   -0.642 0.462 54  -1.389  0.1704 ctrl  treat   1.5
 ctrl - treat   -0.642 0.462 54  -1.389  0.1704 treat ctrl    1.5

day = 2:
 contrast     estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value plus  minus midpt
 ctrl - treat    4.011 0.462 54   8.687  <.0001 ctrl  treat   1.5
 ctrl - treat    4.011 0.462 54   8.687  <.0001 treat ctrl    1.5

day = 3:
 contrast     estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value plus  minus midpt
 ctrl - treat    0.458 0.462 54   0.991  0.3262 ctrl  treat   1.5
 ctrl - treat    0.458 0.462 54   0.991  0.3262 treat ctrl    1.5

Degrees-of-freedom method: df.error
```

#### The problem

The thing is, no matter what adjustment method I use, I get the exact same values. I checked that with `all.equal()`.

```
qq1 <-  emmeans::emmeans(object = m1, data=df,
                   specs = "treat", by = "day",
                   adjust="BH") %>% 
    emmeans::pwpp(by="day")
qq2 <-  emmeans::emmeans(object = m1, data=df,
                   specs = "treat", by = "day",
                   adjust="bonferroni") %>% 
    emmeans::pwpp(by="day")
all.equal(qq1$data, qq2$data)
```

I also checked with the `rstatix` package, which is an nice way of adding these results to `ggplot2`

```
em_res <-
df %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  emmeans_test(formula = value ~ treat) %>% 
  add_xy_position(fun = "max", x = "day", dodge = 0.5)

ggplot(df, aes(day, value, color=treat))+
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.5))+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="line", aes(group=treat)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se, geom="pointrange") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  stat_pvalue_manual(data = em_res, 
                     step.increase = 0.15,
                     label = "{scales::pvalue(p.adj, add_p = T)}",
                     remove.bracket = F)
```

[image]

If I check the table, it might even seem that p.values are not getting adjusted. This is independent of the `p.adjust.method` I choose...

```
em_res
# A tibble: 3 x 15
  day   term  .y.   group1 group2    df statistic        p    p.adj
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 1     treat value ctrl   treat     54    -1.39  1.70e- 1 1.70e- 1
2 2     treat value ctrl   treat     54     8.69  7.81e-12 7.81e-12
3 3     treat value ctrl   treat     54     0.991 3.26e- 1 3.26e- 1
```

What am I missing here?

- Am I using the correct code?
- Is it possible that each leg is being considered separately, and because my treatment has only 2 levels, there is no adjustment to make? Shouldn't we have to adjust for total 3 tests ?

Just to add a bit more info, it looks like the adjustment is being done if I decided to test within treatment across days.

```
em_res <-
df %>% 
  group_by(treat) %>% 
  emmeans_test(formula = value ~ day, 
               p.adjust.method = "bonferroni") %>% # <- This is actually working!
  add_xy_position(fun = "max", x = "day", dodge = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are only two treatments, so there is only one comparison between treatments per group. Adjustments are done separately in each group, unless requested otherwise. Hence there is no multiplicity to adjust for.

Comment: "Adjustments are done separately in each group, **unless requested otherwise.**" How would I request otherwise?

Comment: Summarize the emmGrid object with by = NULL. Please read the "basics" vignette.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and discovered that I was using "adjust" in the wrong place. I was doing:

```
emm <- emmeans(
  model_name,
  response ~ treatment,
  type = "response",
  adjust = "bonferroni",
)
pairs(emm)
```

But adjust needs to be specified in pairs:

```
emm <- emmeans(
  model_name,
  response ~ treatment,
  type = "response"
)
pairs(emm)
pairs(emm, adjust = "bonferroni")
```

This made emmeans provide me with the contrasts adjusted as wished.